# Android Studio moving views around in XML design mode

Tags: android, view

So I recently upgraded my Android Studio as they keep bugging me to do every time I open Studio.  Now I'm having a couple issues that are wasting a ton of time.

First, I've created an activity and put different layouts in the activity.  I use the visibility to show the layout I want and hide all others.  When I go into design mode and hide a layout and make another one visible in order to work on it, my views are moving around.  For example I have one layout that starts off displaying a textview, an edittext, a textview and another edittext...in that order from left to right in a linear layout.  When I set this layout to "gone" and make another layout "visible" so I can work on it and then go back, the views are in the following order...edittext, edittext, textview, textview.  I never had this problem before upgrading to 3.5.  Anyone know why on Earth this is happening?

The second issue is that I used to be able to copy one dialog box I had made and then paste it to the root layout folder with no problems.  Now when I do this the two dialog boxes seem to be tied together somehow.  When I change the name of a view in one dialog box, the name of the mirror view in the other dialog box changes.  Again, this is causing a massive waste of time.  Anyone know why either of these things is happening???

Mark

Comment: Welcome to SO, it's hard to figure out what's going on, but for the first issue, try this out: Android Studio > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML > Arrangement tab; from top right corner, select  “Set from”  > Predefined Styles > Android > press OK.. please let me know if this help you to post it as answer with refined format

Comment: @Zain I was having the same problem after upgrading to 4.0 and your reset suggestion worked for me